# How to use tokens in Gmail Api with service account

Tags: c#, oauth, gmail-api

I'm new to the Google API and to OAuth. In my asp.net application I'm using the Gmail API with a service account. This is my code:

```
       X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(key, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                    {
                        Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
                        User = userEmail
                    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                if (credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                {
                    GmailService service = new GmailService(
                        new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
                        {
                            HttpClientInitializer = credential
                        }
                    );
        //more code
```

I'm doing that for every call to the API, So my question is do I have to store the access token somewhere or is this code good to use as is? And also do I need to disconnect from the service after making an API call? and if yes how?

Comment: You have to store the access token in your database or where ever you want. once you get authorization and authentication to google Api's, you can send request to the API and get data. Its not required to disconnect from service after the call. This access token is short lived token. To to continue for the requests you should get refresh token. check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: @SGC can you show me the code how to do that? Thanks